# Aws ses error: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendBulkTemplatedEmail operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Getting a destination error from a code:

" An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the SendBulkTemplatedEmail operation: You must specify at least 1 destination, and no more than 50 destinations"

This error is from a code I have used several times. I used python to populate the template from a website that I scraped. Please check https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zgcVrmgf2H/ for the JSON template (data has been redacted for data protection).

The code is at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y2xMzctcny/.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON object you provided has 133 destinations in the list.  You'll need some logic to split this up into multiple requests if the list of destinations is > 50.

Comment: is there a way to increase the 50 limits in AWS?

Comment: @Aswin1054 Probably not as [their documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendBulkTemplatedEmail.html) suggests iterating over your list and calling the function multiple times if you need > 50